# Upshot setFilter

Tags: javascript, upshot

I am trying to filter an upshot RemoteDataSource. With the setFilter function I can pass in an array of filters, but at the moment there is no way of specifying whether I want to apply (*filter1* **AND** *filter2*), or (*filter1* **OR** *filter2*). Looking into the upshot.js code, it is clearly visible why:

```
$.each(query.filters, function (index, filter) {
    if (filterParameter) {
        filterParameter += " and ";
    }
    filterParameter += applyOperator(filter.property, filter.operator, filter.value);
});
```

As you can see, the *"and"* is hardcoded into upshot. Is there any other way of supporting *"or"* between filters, or will I have to manually modify things? And if have to modify, what is the best approach to take so that my modifications don't get discarded when I update to a newer version of upshot?

This is the same question as the one on the [ASP.NET forums](http://forums.asp.net/t/1783070.aspx/1?Upshot%20setFilter).

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a horrible hack, but you can do this

```js
self.dataSource.setFilter({ 
    property: "(CustomerId eq 1) or (CustomerId eq 2) and true", 
    operator: "==", 
    value: true });
```

Basically you just need to realize that the upshot filter is a very leaky abstraction on top of the OData $filter. So in the 'property' you can write any OData filter that you want as long as you end it with "true==true"

Reminds me of SQL Injection techniques. I covered data manipulation in Upshot on my blog http://bartjolling.blogspot.com/2012/04/building-single-page-apps-with-aspnet.html

My conclusion was that it's still very far away from being ready for a real business application.

Comment: I guess that would be an option too, but it seems overly difficult to build up and maintain when you have dynamic filter properties. Since it's a hack anyway, it would be easier to just modify the piece of code inside upshot to take into consideration a fourth parameter that would set the `and` or `or` between the filters.

Comment: The code in your question seems to come from the "DataProvider.OData.js" part of Upshot. If I read the constructor for RemoteDataSource correctly, you can pass your own custom dataProvider as a parameter to a RemoteDataSource. This would allow you to filter as you please without less maintenance issues